# How to multi-update the table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, merge, insert

I have these tables called transaction_line_fact and channel_dim:

```
SQL> desc transaction_line_fact
 Name                                                              Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------- -------- --------------------------------------------
 TRANSACTION_ID                                                             NUMBER(20)
 TRANSACTION_LINE_ID                                                        NUMBER(20)
 TRANID                                                                     VARCHAR2(30)
 TRANSACTION_TYPE                                                           VARCHAR2(50)
 TRANDATE                                                                   DATE
 KPI_CHANNEL_SKEY                                                           NUMBER(20)
 KPI_LOCATION_SKEY                                                          NUMBER(20)
 KPI_DEPARTMENT_SKEY                                                        NUMBER(20)
 KPI_ITEM_SKEY                                                              NUMBER(20)
 AMOUNT                                                                     NUMBER(8,2)
 COST                                                                       NUMBER(8,2)
 UNITS                                                                      NUMBER(5)
 KPI_DW_SKEY                                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(20)

SQL> desc channel_dim
 Name                                                              Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------- -------- --------------------------------------------
 DATE_CREATED                                                               DATE
 IS_RECORD_INACTIVE                                                         CHAR(1)
 LAST_MODIFIED_DATE                                                         DATE
 LIST_ID                                                                    NUMBER(20)
 LIST_ITEM_NAME                                                             VARCHAR2(20)
 KPI_DW_SKEY                                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(20)
 KPI_DW_INSERT_DATE                                                         DATE
 KPI_DW_UPDATE_DATE                                                         DATE
```

Currently the in transaction_line_fact table `KPI_CHANNEL_SKEY` contains null values but I want to populate it with the help of `KPI_DW_SKEY` column in channel_dim.

Also I've tried doing this way:

```
SQL> update transaction_line_fact set kpi_channel_skey = (select c.kpi_dw_skey from channel_dim c join transaction_line_fact t on c.kpi_dw_skey=t.kpi_dw_skey);
update transaction_line_fact set kpi_channel_skey = (select c.kpi_dw_skey from channel_dim c join transaction_line_fact t on c.kpi_dw_skey=t.kpi_dw_skey)
                                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row


SQL> update transaction_line_fact set kpi_channel_skey = (select kpi_dw_skey from channel_dim) where kpi_channel_skey is null;
update transaction_line_fact set kpi_channel_skey = (select kpi_dw_skey from channel_dim) where kpi_channel_skey is null
                                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row


SQL> update transaction_line_fact set kpi_channel_skey in (select kpi_dw_skey from channel_dim) where kpi_channel_skey is null;
update transaction_line_fact set kpi_channel_skey in (select kpi_dw_skey from channel_dim) where kpi_channel_skey is null
                                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00927: missing equal sign
```

But again it shows error like `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Any idea on How to populate it?
Thank You so much!

Comment: You try to update single value with a result set: **If you were a DBMS, what will you do in this case?**

Comment: Ahh! Got it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax would be

```
UPDATE transaction_line_fact f
   SET f.kpi_channel_skey =
          (SELECT c.kpi_dw_skey
             FROM channel_dim c
            WHERE c.kpi_dw_skey = f.kpi_dw_skey);
```

In other words, you have to join `channel_dim` with `transaction_line_fact`, but not specifying that table once again in a subquery, but using a `where` clause to join appropriate columns.

---

Although this is now "OK" as far as the principle is concerned, I can't tell whether it will (or will not) raise an error; `too_many_rows` could happen again, but - in that case - you have to decide what to do if for the same `kpi_dw_skey` `channel_dim` contains more than a single row - will you take only one (which one?), or ... Really, can't tell.